# Spring Data 2.x: adding customer behavior to all repositories

Tags: spring-data

I have a web app that was built with Spring Data 1.6.1.RELEASE. It adds custom behavior too all repositories by following the example in the Spring Data' online documentation here:

1.3.2 Adding custom behavior to all repositories
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Basically, it extends JpaRepository with custom behavior shown below:

```
public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
  extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

  void sharedCustomMethod(ID id);
}
```

Here is the code for implementation of this new interface:

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public MyRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(domainClass, entityManager);

    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
    // implementation goes here
  }
}
```

Custom repository factory bean:

```
public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
  extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

    return new MyRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  }

  private static class MyRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
      super(entityManager);

      this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

      return new MyRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainClass(), entityManager);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

      // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
      //to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
      return MyRepository.class;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the declaration of the factory bean:

```
<repositories base-package="com.acme.repository"
  factory-class="com.acme.MyRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

Everything works well with Spring Data 1.6.1.RELEASE. However, I got the following exception when starting Jetty in Eclipse after I switched to Spring Data 2.3.2.RELEASE:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface com.acme.repository.MyRepository to match the given arguments: [class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation, class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52]. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$4(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:522)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:522)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
```

What can I try to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I added the following constructor but still have the same problem:

```
public MyRepositoryImpl(
        JpaMetamodelEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation,
        EntityManager entityManager) {
   super(entityInformation, entityManager);
   this.em = entityManager;
```

}

Comment: Does if you point to @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class) the repository implementation directly?

Comment: @JavierHeisecke thanks for chiming in! Do you mean that in the xml, I should use factory-class="com.acme.MyRepositoryImpl" ? Could you please tell me the details of what I should try exactly? I did gogole search before and saw something similar to your suggestion, but not sure how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just setup an application with `2.3.2.RELEASE` and its look like it has been simplified.

1. Delete `MyRepositoryFactoryBean`
2. Replace `<repositories base-package="com.acme.repository...` with

```
    <repositories base-package="com.acme.repository"
     base-class="….MyRepositoryImpl" />
```

3. `MyRepositoryImpl`

```
    public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

       private EntityManager entityManager;

       MyRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation,
                     EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);

        // Keep the EntityManager around to used from the newly introduced 

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
       }

       public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
        // implementation goes here
       }
     }
```

4. Make sure `MyRepository` is outside the package `base-package` i.e `com.acme.repository`.

**Note**

- `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)` on a class annotated `@Configuration` is equivalent to point 2. As long as the package of that configuration class is `com.acme.repository`
- `@NoRepositoryBean`  annotation on `MyRepository` is equivalent to point 4

**Sample Spring boot app with java config for reference**

- https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoveflow-63223076
- Import it as maven project to your IDE. Right click on `AccessingDataJpaApplication` and run, it will start, save some entities and call your custom method

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! I tested your program and it works well. However, I have problem incorporating your solution into my existing app. The app already has other Spring Data repositories defined through @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.repository.repository"). It seems that I am not able to add another one as you indicated: @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class). How can I address this issue? All repositories read/write the same database.

Comment: Try modifying the existing one like `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.repository.repository", repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)` instead of adding the annotation second time

Comment: Did what you suggested. But when I started the site, I got this error:

Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myCustomerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCustomerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void MyRepository.sharedCustomMethod(java.io.Serializable)! No property sharedCustomMethod found for type Customer!

Comment: I have this resporsitory: @Repository("myCustomerRepository")
public interface MyCustomerRepository extends MyRepository<Customer, Integer>

Comment: It seems like it is not recognising your `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)`. Because if I change it to only `@EnableJpaRepositories` in my sample app, I am getting the same exception

Comment: Are you using spring-boot too?

Comment: Yes. I use a SpringBoot app in order to incorporate your solution. I use this one for the test: springmvc5-springdatajpa2-jsp-mysql-example downloaded from https://github.com/RameshMF/spring-mvc-tutorial I am able to run this example site without any problem. Got the same error as you saw when adding your solution.

Comment: Were you using `<repositories base-package="com.acme.repository` or `java annotation` this in 1.6.1? And are you currently using only `java config` for every spring configuration or do you use both?

Comment: My original app uses Spring Data 1.6.1 and the whole site's configuration is in XML. The  online tutorial app I use to test the integration of your solution uses Spring Data 2.x and the entire app is in java annotation. No mix of XML configuration and java annotation in either scenario.

Comment: So you took this `springmvc5-springdatajpa2-jsp-mysql-example` and added only common repo method and configs  and trying to get it work?

Comment: I am using `springmvc5-springdatajpa2-jsp-mysql-example` now and added the two classes from your solution into it. Then I added a new class: @Repository("myCustomerRepository")
public interface MyCustomerRepository extends MyRepository<Customer, Integer> { 
}. All repo related classes are in the same folder: net.javaguides.springmvc.repository.

Comment: Well. That sample app is not `spring boot` app. It is only spring app and was not updated for 2 years. May be you should try his other sample with spring boot jpa,jsp, mysql .https://github.com/RameshMF/springboot2-webapp-jsp and add `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)` on top of `Springboot2WebappJspApplication`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not really familiar with Spring Boot. I downloaded the sample app you mentioned and got it working first. Then incorporated your classes to the repositories folder, created a new repository class public interface User2Repository extends MyRepository<User, Integer>. The site is still working! I have selected your post as the ANSWER.